# Why a crystal lattice with short axes would have a diffraction pattern in which spots would appear far apart using Bragg's law?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

With the aid of Bragg's law, explain why a crystal lattice with short axes would have a diffraction pattern in which spots would appear far apart?

Comment: That is what the Fourier transform does - high spatial frequency (close atoms) means high momentum transfers (larger $k$ vectors) leading to diffraction spots farther apart back in real space.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.